# What is the argument of 8i?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Since  **8i**   don't have any real part. so, we can assume it's real part as  *0*  but *tangent* of zero degree is undefined. Then what is the argument of it?

Comment: Well...$re^{i\theta}=r(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta)$.  Can you solve for $r, \theta$ given that you want this to be $8i$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Just like $i$: $\;\dfrac\pi2$.

Comment: Hint: Plot $8i$ in the complex plane. What angle results counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis to $8i$?

Comment: The arctangent is how you would use a calculator to find the arguments of most complex numbers. But it is _not_ the definition of argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition the principal argument $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ in usually defined in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$ therefore

$$\operatorname{Arg}(8i)=\pi/2$$

If we do not refer to the principal value therefore we can use any

$$\arg(8i)=\pi/2+2k\pi \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

that is

$$8i=8e^{i(\pi/2+2k\pi)}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Just  find the point $8i$ in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

In the complex plane, $8i$ is on the positive part of the $y-$axis, so the angle from the positive part of the $x-$axis is well-defined and equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Note that you have :
$$8i = 8 e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $8i=0+8i$ is on the imaginary axis.  The argument is $\frac \pi 2$ as that is the angle from the positive real axis to the positive imaginary axis.  The formula for the argument uses the arctangent (not the tangent) and breaks down for angles $\pm \frac \pi 2$ because the ratio of imaginary part to real part is not defined.